# ArgumentParser optional multiple subparsers

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I'm trying to get a configuration for a pipeline script, where my program provides three different actions with their own parameters. I want to be able to selectively run one of the three, or also combine them in a sequence defined by the order of the arguments, for example:

```markdown
action1
  --p1 (parameter for 1 only)
action2
  --p2 (parameter for 2 only)
--p (global parameter)
...
```

I would like to be able to do `python main.py action1 --p1` or `python main.py action2 --p2` but also `python main.py action1 --p1 action2 --p2`

I thought I would solve this with subparsers with the 'append' action

```py
parser = ArgumentParser()
subparse = parser.add_subparsers(dest="op", action='append')
t = subparse.add_parser("action1")
t.add_argument("--p1", type=int, default=10)
v = subparse.add_parser('action2')
v.add_argument("--p2", type=int, default=1)
```

but this fails:

```
  File "C:\Users\andre\example.py", line 231, in <module>
    subparse = parser.add_subparsers(dest="action", action='append')
  File "C:\Users\andre\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.9.13\lib\argparse.py", line 1798, in add_subparsers
    action = parsers_class(option_strings=[], **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parser_class'
```

Why is this not working, and which other strategy could I use to solve this?

Comment: you can't do that.  Only one subparser per call

Comment: `subparse` is a `positional` argument with a specialized `Action` subclass, with a defined `nargs` ('+....') and `choices`.  When main encounters this, it calls the subparser (e.g. `action1`) giving all the remaining `argv` strings.  When `action1` is done, parsing is done.    In short `parser` handles what it can, and hands the task off to `action1`.  So there's no way of doing multiple subcommands.

Comment: Ok, I think I better understand the purpose of the subparser now. Pity that there is no simple way of doing this, it could come handy in some circumstances.

Comment: People have set up nested subparsers.  But multiple sequential ones would require a different mechanism, and I haven't seen a serious proposal for that.  There may be something on `pypi`